# Get token with JWT without attempting user credentials Laravel?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm currently working on a Angular (Front End) - Laravel (API) application. I need to know whether I can make a hybrid log in.

Currently I'm using a stored procedure for the log in. But then if the login was succesful I want to send a JWT token to the client side. Is this possible without calling the JWT attempt method? Does JWT has something like a **JWT::getToken($mail);** method? If I can't do this, are any other work arounds?

```
$mail = $request['email'];
$password = $request['password'];

$query = new Query("CALL SP_USER_LOG_IN(?,?, @outputMessage)");
$query->addParameter(1, $mail);
$query->addParameter(2, $password);

$outputMessage = DB::executeQuery($query);

if($outputMessage === null)
{
    //It means the login was successful
    $token = JWT::getToken($mail);

    return ["error" => NULL, "token" => $token];
}
else
{
    return ["error" => $outputMessage];
}
```

**NOTE**

I just found out about JWT and it looks like a really good solution since I'm working with a light angular application on the front end. But since I must use a stored procedure, I don't how to proceed.

Comment: are you using a package to generate the JWT?

Comment: Yes I am. Currently using JWT for Laravel

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Maybe a package name or link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've verified the user, grab them from the database then create the token `fromUser($user)`.

```
if($outputMessage === null)
{
    //It means the login was successful
    $user = User::where('email', $mail)->first();
    $token = JWT::fromUser($user);

    return ["error" => NULL, "token" => $token];
}
```

Comment: Man you saved my life! Thank you! This works like a charm!